# Python Discord Bot | How do I mention someone in embed?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to do mention users in embed. My current code is:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def cr_embsuc(ctx, bot, ad, irk, sinif):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Başarıyla karakter oluşturuldu.", color=0x0b9310)
        embed.set_author(name="DcRPG - Character Creation", icon_url=bot.user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name=str(ctx.author)+" isimli kullanıcının karakteri ", value="Ad : "+ad+"\n"+"Irk : "+irk+"\n"+"Sınıf : "+sinif,
                        inline=True, )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-512.png")
        embed.set_footer(text="Footeroe", icon_url=bot.user.avatar_url)
        return ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Result look like this:

[image]

And I want it to be like this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mention someone by using [`discord.Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention). But as far as I know, you cannot mention someone in the `name` of the embed or field. So you can basically do:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Başarıyla karakter oluşturuldu.", color=0x0b9310)
embed.add_field(name=str(ctx.author), value=ctx.author.mention)
```